# Adding the number of students

Tags: c

Trying to make a program that will store information of students and so far I got a problem when the user should choose the nummber of students that should be stored. maybe i have missed something but i cant find it, when i instead of using in this case n (number of students to be stored) as 10 it works fine and then 10 students gets registered but now i want to change this so the user should choose how many students to add.

At the moment after the user chooses the number of students it skips the "storing information" part and jumps to the end so my guess is that it must be n that is the problem.

```
    struct student
    {
      char name[50], number[13], gender[6], program[50], age[3], email[100];
      int roll;
    } s[10];

    main();

    int i, n;

    printf("Enter how many students to add:\n");
    scanf("%s", &n);

    // storing information
    i = 0;
    for (i; i < n; ++i)
    {
        s[i].roll = i + 1;

        printf("\nFor roll number%d\n", s[i].roll);   //number of the student

        printf("Enter name: \n");
        scanf("%s", s[i].name);

        printf("Enter personal number (yyyymmdd-xxxx):\n");
        scanf("%s", &s[i].number);

        printf("Enter gender (male or female):\n");
        scanf("%s", &s[i].gender);

        printf("Enter program of student: \n");
        scanf("%s", &s[i].program);

        printf("Enter age of student: \n");
        scanf("%s", &s[i].age);

        printf("Enter email of student: \n");
        scanf("%s", &s[i].email);

        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("Displaying Information:\n");
```

Comment: `scanf("%s", &n);` -> `scanf("%d", &n);` - Wrong format specifier

Comment: Did you really copy your code? `main();` seems like it should be the `int main() {`. If this really is your code I'd say calling `main` is fishy.

Comment: What is expected to be entered when asked for "gender"? Be aware that `gender[6]` cannot hold the string "female". Please always provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) .Your code is neither complete, nor compilable.

Comment: the question is abut a run-time problem.  For such problems please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%s", &n);`  1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  2) This is trying to read an integer, but the input format specifier '%s' is for reading a string, until the first 'white space'  suggest using: '%d'.  Note: if actually trying to read a string, then always include a MAX_CHARACTERS modifier that is one less than the length of the input buffer because '%s' and '%[...]' always append a NUL byte to the input.  This also avoids any possibility of a buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behaivor

Comment: regarding: `main()`  The function `main()` should never be called by 'user' code. Suggest implementing a loop inside the `main()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct student
{
  char name[50], number[13], gender[6], program[50], age[3], email[100];
  int roll;
} s[10];

int main(){

int i, n;

printf("Enter how many students to add:\n");
// the problem was here
scanf("%d", &n);

// storing information
i = 0;
for (i; i < n; ++i)
{
    s[i].roll = i + 1;

    printf("\nFor roll number%d\n", s[i].roll);   //number of the student

    printf("Enter name: \n");
    scanf("%s", s[i].name);

    printf("Enter personal number (yyyymmdd-xxxx):\n");
    scanf("%s", &s[i].number);

    printf("Enter gender (male or female):\n");
    scanf("%s", &s[i].gender);

    printf("Enter program of student: \n");
    scanf("%s", &s[i].program);

    printf("Enter age of student: \n");
    scanf("%s", &s[i].age);

    printf("Enter email of student: \n");
    scanf("%s", &s[i].email);

    printf("\n");
}

printf("Displaying Information:\n");}
```

the %s format is for strings and %d for integer